# Mount NFS volume on Ubuntu Linux server from macOS client

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, nfs

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server (a local VM in my case). How do I mount a directory on the Linux server from a macOS Catalina client, using NFS?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Setting up the Linux server

1. Install the NFS server as per the [Ubuntu NFS guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-nfs):

   ```
   sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/exports`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/exports
   ```

   Now add a line similar to this:

   ```
   /home/ubuntu 172.16.238.0/24(insecure,rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
   ```

   - `/home/ubuntu` is the directory to export
   - `172.16.238.0/24` is the IP addresses to accept connections from. The Mac client's IP address should be in this range. Use `*` to allow from any IP address. (But be careful not to make your NFS server available to the entire internet!)
   - `insecure` means to accept connections from unprivileged (higher) port numbers
   - `rw` means read-write
   - `all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000` forces all reads and writes to be performed by the user/group with UID/GID 1000 (1000 is the default `ubuntu` user/group on my server). Run the `id` command on the server to find out your UID/GID. You need these options unless your Ubuntu server and Mac client use the same UID/GID for the main user.
   - `no_subtree_check` is a performance thing
3. Save the file and run

   ```
   sudo exportfs -vra
   ```

   to reload the NFS exports. (I'm not sure if the `-a` option is necessary.)

### Setting up the Mac client

1. On the macOS client, edit the `/etc/auto_master` file (documented in the [`auto_master man page`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/5/auto_master/#neo-man-table-output)):

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/auto_master
   ```

   and change the line starting with `/net` to the following (or add it if necessary):

   ```
   /net                    -hosts          -nobrowse,nosuid,locallocks,nfc,actimeo=1
   ```

   - `locallocks` creates locks on the client rather than on the server. Without this, Finder becomes very slow and takes forever to show directories.
   - `nfc` makes UTF-8 file names work
   - `actimeo=1` sets the attribute cache timeout as short as possible. Note that setting it to `0` (or adding `noac`) causes Finder not to notice when a file is deleted on the server, so we can't use it.
   - Note that we're not using `nfsvers=4` here. I got kernel panics on the Mac with this, so I went back to the default (NFSv3).

   Note: It appears that some macOS software updates can overwrite this file and remove your changes. I've found myself having to go back to back to this answer once a year or so re-apply the changes.
2. Refresh the automounts by running

   ```
   sudo automount -vc
   ```

   (If you previously tried to mount an NFS volume, unmount it first, like so: `sudo umount -f /net/fileserver.local/home/ubuntu`)
3. In the Finder menu, select Go -> Go to Folder, and type `/net/SERVER_HOST_NAME`, e.g. `/net/fileserver.local`.

   You should find your exported directory in there, e.g. at `/net/fileserver.local/home/ubuntu`. Drag this directory to the Finder sidebar to make it easy to access in the future.

Comment: Also, is there any way to fix the permissions. The only way I have to access my files from the Mac is giving 777 permissions to the folder I want to share :( otherwise the system shows me a message telling my I don't have permissions to browse the folder.

Comment: @carlosvega The `all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000` options take care of permissions for me - everything owned by UID 1000 on the Ubuntu server can be accessed from the Mac client no problem, so there's no need for chmodding to 777.

Comment: Just a quick comment, if you just want to mount "on the fly" on the mac side, this works for me : `sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport 172.16.238.x:/home/ubuntu /Users/xyz/ubuntu`

Comment: works for me with Mac OSX Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: People don't realize how much trial and error lies behind this brilliant answer. Especially the "nfc" part is CRUCIAL when mounting (or `rsync`ing) non-MacOS servers. You won't notice at first, but the UTF-8 ain't the same on OS X as it is everywhere else. Without it, your file names might very well be garbled and require hours on end to fix later on. I know I can't use a comment to say, "thank you," so I'll just end it here ;)

Comment: `locallocks` is a huge performance booster! thank you heaps for that one!

Comment: If I could upvote this answer a million times I would. Thanks you so much. I've been trying for weeks to setup NFS on an Ubuntu server and mount it on MacOS, and trawled the web far and wide and never could get it to work. None of all the "respectable answers" (from DigitalOcean, etc.) worked at all. This is probably the most useful technical answer I've gotten online ever. Thanks again.